# MSCRM, retrieve entity forms list

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need a list of all forms for a given entity (multiform); I know a solution in client side Javascript code but I am using server side code.

I tried using this message to get the entity metadata but I can't find it there:

```
    RetrieveEntityRequest mdRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest()
    {
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
        LogicalName = entityName,
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
    };
```

I tried retrieving the entity FormXML but it's not there either:

```
private string GetFormXML(int objectTypeCode)
{
        QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("systemform");
        q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("formxml");
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("type", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, objectTypeCode));

        var entities = ctx.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(q);

        if (entities != null)
        {
            return entities.Entities.First().Attributes["formxml"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried your code and got "a list of all forms for a given entity" what isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think systemform entity has objecttypecode as string which accepts the entity name rather than real entity object type code. Can you try changing the object type code from number to entity name?

```
private string GetFormXML(int objectTypeCode)
{
        QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("systemform");
        q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("formxml");
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("type", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, "contact"));

        var entities = ctx.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(q);

        if (entities != null)
        {
            return entities.Entities.First().Attributes["formxml"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
}
```

Comment: i have no problem with retrieving the FormXml , i can't find what i am looking for there.
i am looking for the formid description

Comment: Didnt you try? queryExpression.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("formxml","formid","description");

Answer (score 0):

```
        public Dictionary<Guid, string> GetNevegationItems(int objectTypeCode)
    {
        QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("systemform");
        q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "formid");
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("type", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2));
        q.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, objectTypeCode));

        var entities = ctx.OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(q);

        if (entities != null)
        {
            Dictionary<Guid, string> rslt = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
            foreach (var item in entities.Entities)
            {
                rslt.Add(item.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("formid"), item.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"));
            }
            return rslt;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```